# Unexpected output of pandas df.corr method

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on an exercise where I need to define with the Pearson's method (df.corr) of the panda's 0.18.1 library the correlation between two columns in a `dataframe`.

The problem is that I was continuously not getting the answer and after some basic debugging I came up with the below paradox.

[image]

As you can see, I try to correlate the Energy Supply per Capita with itself that must give 1.0 as the answer but instead it outputs what you can see below. I tried then to determine whether it is indeed empty and it is not. I don't know what to do and any help would be kindly accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that something is off with your Energy Supply per Capita data; perhaps you have non-numeric data in the column or an empty column. It's hard to know without seeing how you built the Top15 DataFrame.

(Incidentally, I took the same course as the one you are doing, so I'll give you unrelated advice: That question can be answered in as few as four lines!)